# How to perform autoclearing associated table rows without valid associated id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I am trying to find a way to clear rows from table which is associated with another table.

The point is that I am trying to create application for recipes.
And for example I don't want to have situation when 2 or more recipes have same ingredient (let's say eggs). And if I remove one recipe it will remove automatically associated Active Record but I want to remove it when e.g. eggs won't be used in another recipe.

Ingredient Model:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :ingredients

end
```

Recipe Model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :recipe
    has_many :directions, inverse_of: :recipe

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['step'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true

    validates :tittle, :description, :image, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

So is there any way (excluding sql queries) to perform such operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a join table that joins Recipe and Ingredient. This is required to setup a many to many association.

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients,
     reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
     allow_destroy: true

  # ...
end

# This model is the master table for ingredients 
# using a normalized table avoids duplication
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

# This contains the quantity of an ingredient used in a recipe
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredients
end
```

You can then remove orphaned rows by creating a callback:

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredients

  after_destroy do |record|
    ingredient = record.ingredient
    unless ingredient.recipe_ingredients.any?
      ingredient.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: all seems fine but as beginer I have no idea how to implement this .... :(